# Printing all the cycles in an adjacency matrix using python

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

In the below code, while trying to print all cycles, there comes the case where multiple cycles exist for one node. Even though I am increasing the value of k in the cycle function, it doesn't print all the possible cycles for a given node i.e. it doesn't consider the two possible cycles for node 3 or index 2 to index 1  as well as index 3 of the node 1 or index 0. Here we discuss the following graph, represented as `mat` in the code. [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNuso.png)

output the code prints:

```
['1 -> 2', '2 -> 3', '3 -> 1']

['1 -> 4', '4 -> 5', '5 -> 1']

['2 -> 3', '3 -> 1', '1 -> 2']

['3 -> 1', '1 -> 2', '2 -> 3']
```

Where the code fails is on the path `[ [3 -> 1 ] , [1 -> 4] , [4-> 5] , [5-> 1] , [1 -> 2] , [2-> 3]]`. With this code, I aim to print all cycles for a given adjacency matrix, even considering the case where no cycles exist.

I expect the output for the given an example as:

```
['1 -> 2', '2 -> 3', '3 -> 1']

['1 -> 4', '4 -> 5', '5 -> 1']

['2 -> 3', '3 -> 1', '1 -> 2']

['3 -> 1', '1 -> 2', '2 -> 3']

['2 -> 3', '3 -> 1', '1 -> 4', '4 -> 5', '5 -> 1', '1 -> 2']

['3 -> 1', '1 -> 4', '4 -> 5', '5 -> 1', '1 -> 2', '2 -> 3']

['4 -> 5', '5 -> 1', '1 -> 2', '2 -> 3', '3 -> 1', '1 -> 4']

['5 -> 1', '1 -> 2', '2 -> 3', '3 -> 1', '1 -> 4', '4 -> 5']
```

---

Code Sample:

```py
mat = [[0,1,0,1,0] , [0,0,1,0,0] , [1,0,0,0,0] , [0,0,0,0,1] , [1,0,0,0,0]]

def cycle(mat,i,j,find):  
    global temp,t
    k = 0
    while k != len(mat): 
        if k != j and mat[j][k] and (temp == [] or temp[-1][-1] == str(j+1)):
            temp.append(f'{j+1} -> {k+1}')
            if k == find:
                print(temp)
                return 1
            else:
                t.append([i,j,k,find])
                if t.count([i,j,k,find]) > 1:
                    return -1
                cycle(mat,j,k,find)      
        k = k+1
        
                
for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(len(mat)):
        if mat[i][j] and i != j:
            temp = []
            t = []
            temp.append(f'{i+1} -> {j+1}')
            cycle(mat,i,j,i)
```

Logic:

We are trying to go from :   i -> j    to :  j -> k   (where i , j , k  are nodes) using cycle function. I've used

```
(temp == [] or temp[-1][-1] == str(j+1))
```

to make sure that after i -> j , only j -> k gets appended

```
                t.append([i,j,k,find])
                if t.count([i,j,k,find]) > 1:
                    return -1
```

conditions to prevent it from going into infinite recursion. For Detailed Logic [click](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xxrMgepVkeCYCMkjAyY3S0AqM35wwr2mx09LMUpXvuQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Thank you for your time and for helping me with my first StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

You say you expect  [ [3 -> 1 ] , [1 -> 4] , [4-> 5] , [5-> 1] , [1 -> 2] , [2-> 3]] but this is just a combination of two cycles which ARE printed out.   [1 -> 4] , [4-> 5] , [5-> 1] and [3->1] , [1 -> 2] , [2-> 3].

It seems unreasonable to me to expect two cycles that just happen to share a node to be output as a combination.  If you really do want to see this, then take the output of uncombined cycles, check them for shared nodes and print out the combined cycles as they are found.

```
FIND simple cycles ( using your code )
LOOP over pairs of simple cycles
   IF pair share nodes
       PRINT combined cycle
```

Comment: The detailed logic is : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xxrMgepVkeCYCMkjAyY3S0AqM35wwr2mx09LMUpXvuQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you get an intuition of how the code works ?

Comment: I deleted all the meaningless comments.

Comment: Do you mean your code?  Your code works fine.  It finds the simple cycles.  If you want to see the combined cycles, then my answer describes how to do so.

Comment: My code will never print uncombined cycles because assuming there is a cycle from node '3' it will only print paths that start from '3' and end at '3', No question of uncombined cycles.

Comment: You code prints simple cycles.  The example you posted in your question shows it doing so.